# Display two values foreign key in kendo Grid MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm so tired to resolve this problem. I just want to display two values, For example in `columns.Foreignkey`. Showing `Name` and `Id` on the same columns. How do I do this?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Project_Test.Models.Workcenter>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.WorkcenterCode)
            .Width(80)
            .Title("Workcentercode")
            .ClientTemplate("");
        columns.Bound(p => p.WorkCenterSection)
            .Width(84)
            .Title("WorkcenterSection");
            
        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.WorkcenterCategory, 
                           (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewBag.WorkcenterCategory,
                           "WorkcenterCategoryID",
                           "WorkcenterCategoryName")
            .Title("Category")
            .Width(200);

        //command.Custom("Details").Click("showDetails").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-font-icon  k-i-insert-unordered-list " });
        command.Custom(" ")
            .Click("showDetails")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-xs  glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" })
            .Width(230);
    })
    //.Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBound"))
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable
        .Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
        .TemplateName("Workcent")
        .DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Are you sure to delete this Workcenter")
    )
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(true)
        .Messages(messages => messages.Refresh("Click to refresh"))
        .ButtonCount(8)
    )
    .Groupable()
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Selectable()
    .Scrollable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:580px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.WorkcenterID);
            model.Field(p => p.WorkcenterID).Editable(true);
            model.Field(p => p.UpdatedBy).DefaultValue(User.Identity.Name);
            model.Field(p => p.CreatedBy).DefaultValue(User.Identity.Name);
        })
        .Create(update => update.Action("Employee_Create", "Home"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("List", "Home"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Products_Update", "Home"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("adress_Destroy", "Home"))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ForeignKey` column is just displaying the `WorkcenterCategoryName` associated with the corresponding `WorkcenterCategoryID` from the bound `list(ViewBag.WorkcenterCategory)`.

Just make the `WorkcenterCategoryName` of each element in `ViewBag.WorkcenterCategory` contain the text you actually want to display, i.e.

```
"IDOfSelectedItem (TextOfSelectedItem)"
```

instead of just

```
"TextOfSelectedItem"
```

Edit to be more specific:

I'm assuming your server action is filling `ViewBag.WorkcenterCategory` something like:

```
ViewBag.WorkcenterCategory = GetWorkcenterCategories()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        WorkcenterID = x.ID,
        WorkcenterName = x.Name
    });
```

Let's say this returns the list:

```
{ WorkcenterID = 1, WorkcenterName = "One" },
{ WorkcenterID = 2, WorkcenterName = "Two" }
```

Then the `ForeignKey` column maps a particular key to the corresponding item in the list bound to it (`ViewBag.WorkcenterCategory`) and the text value associated to the key will be displayed, whatever is contained in the `WorkcenterName` field.
i.e. value of 1 will display "One" in the grid.

If you want to display more than just the name of the Workcenter, then set the `WorkcenterName` of the objects in the `ViewBag.WorkcenterCategory` list to the text you want to have displayed, i.e.:

```
ViewBag.WorkcenterCategory = GetWorkcenterCategories()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        WorkcenterID = x.ID,
        WorkcenterName = x.ID + " (" + x.Name + ")"
    });
```

This would return the list:

```
{ WorkcenterID = 1, WorkcenterName = "1 (One)" },
{ WorkcenterID = 2, WorkcenterName = "2 (Two)" }
```

And a value of 1 would now display "1 (One)" instead of just "One".

Comment: Heey I dont understand what is mean "TextOfSelectedItem" I just want to diplay two values FK in Grid how I do this please explain more